# How I can type half-space char in the desktop skype application?

Tags: skype, farsi

Can anyone explain to me that how I can type half-space char in the desktop Skype application? In Persian Language we can use the half-space char but skype prevents us to do this. When we type half-space char (shift space), skype seems to remove this char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What such an interesting issue! I also have that problem. It seems to me it's a bug that Skype couldn't support the Persian Language correctly. I reckon it should be submitted as an issue for Skype.